# How to change model of a combobox (Ext JS) from outside its definition

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

i have two Ext Combo boxes here, i need to change values of second combobox when select event of combobox1 invokes, my problem is i don't know how to change model of a combobox.

```
   items: [{
        xtype:'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Course',
        afterLabelTextTpl: required,     
        store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            data: [
                [1, 'Bsc CS'],
                [2, 'MSc CS'],
            ],
            id: 0,
            fields: ['value', 'text']
        }),             
        name: 'first',
        listeners:{

          select: function( combo, records, eOpts )
          {
              if(this.getValue()=="Bsc CS")
              {
                 // Ext.get('semcombo').getStore.loadData(msc);
              }
              else if(this.getValue()=="MSc CS")
              {

              }
          }  

        },
        editable:false,
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        xtype:'combo',
        fieldLabel: 'Semester',
        id : 'semcombo',
        afterLabelTextTpl: required,
        name: 'last',
        allowBlank: false,
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by model?  The records?

Comment: Yeah. I thought model is the apt word for that.

Comment: Well... model is actually the object that defines a single record's structure.  Technically the term is interchangeable but in this case record is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For the second combobox, configure a combobox for each model type. Hide or show the appropriate combobox as a selection is made in the first combobox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **change the data** completely (**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpdeC/)**)

```
select: function(checkbox,records) {
      comp.clearValue();
      comp.bindStore(Ext.StoreMgr.lookup(records[0].data.store));
      // you can change the value field if needed
      comp.displayField = 'petname'; 
      // you can change the display field if needed
      comp.valueField = 'id'; 
      // you can change the display template if needed
      comp.displayTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
          '<tpl for=".">' +
              '{[typeof values === "string" ? values : values["' + comp.displayField + '"]]}' +
              '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">' + comp.delimiter + '</tpl>' +
          '</tpl>'
      );
      comp.picker = null;
 }
```

If you just **need to filter** (load) the data in second combox you can do something like this

On the select event of the first combobox prepare the second one to filter the data

```
combobox2.queryData = [{ property: 'fieldName', value: value}];
combobox2.reset();
combobox2.doQuery(combobox.queryData);
```

where `combobox2` is a reference to the activated combo and `value` a propertyvalue from the combo. To ensure the use of your new query use

```
combobox2.on('beforequery', function (e) {
    e.query = e.combo.queryData;
});
```